# Import Solution hangs before showing Solution Information

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Trying to import a managed solution to an on premise Dynamics CRM 2011 organisation.

Have done this successfully to another organisation on the same server with the same solution a few weeks ago.

This time it hangs on the Import Solution screen for hours:[image: Import Solution screen]

I never get to see the solution information. I've tried several times.

How can I investigate the cause?

Comment: Just wondering : is it just the screen hanging? Or didn't the solution import at all. If you cancel out, is the solution imported or not?

Comment: @JorisVanRegemortel Cancel stops the import. Remember that I never get to see the solution information - it never even starts importing.

Comment: Which Rollup are you running on?

Comment: Turn on Trace Logging to see if there are any errors...

Comment: @JorisVanRegemortel Rollup 13. It's very strange cos I did exactly the same thing 11 days ago and nothing has changed as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following all of these instructions solved the problem:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918609